# Unable to start logstash in single node setup

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elk

Getting below error while starting the logstash.

> [2023-05-03T00:46:56,556][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][FI] Failed to perform request {:message=>"PKIX path validation failed: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Path does not chain with any of the trust anchors", :exception=>Manticore::ClientProtocolException, :cause=>javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path validation failed: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Path does not chain with any of the trust anchors}

I am not using any cluster setup. All the stack is present on single node only.

Comment: The error "PKIX path validation failed" typically occurs when there is an issue with the SSL/TLS certificate presented by the Elasticsearch instance.